How to configure DNS for full site CDN with separate domains per each language?
I have website example.com. I want to serve it via Cloudfront CDN. It's a multilingual site with separate domains for each language version. The languages apply to only one predefined subdomain or domain, so either for example origin.example.com is in English, or example.com. I also have example.fr and so on.
How to properly configure DNS records for full site CDN?
I have now:

Configured WPML in Wordpress to use origin.example.com for English version.
origin.example.com with A record pointing to my server IP. It loads English website correctly.
example.com ALIAS record pointing to my cloudfront domain. It does load the correct language version, however all urls use origin.example.com, everything loads from origin. Same issue if I visit cloudfront domain.
I can access all files from cloudfront domain if I manually change origin urls.
In cloudfront settings I configured origin.example.com as the origin and put example.com as alternate domain.

How can I avoid origin urls being loaded when accessing example.com? If I pass the Host header I get redirected to my main Wordpress url.
Everything I tried leads to a loop. Thanks for any advice.

Unfortunately this does not seem possible with WPML domain translations. Best I could do was relative path urls rewrite code, but it breaks many ajax tasks. It would work for a static site though.
    function buffer_start() {
    ob_start('replace_urls_with_relative');
}
function buffer_end() {
    ob_end_flush();
}
function replace_urls_with_relative($buffer) {
    $site_url = site_url();
    return str_replace($site_url, '', $buffer);
}

// Start output buffering on init
add_action('init', 'buffer_start');
// End output buffering before sending the page
add_action('shutdown', 'buffer_end');

